# Google Maps' Roads API not working with XHR

Tags: javascript, google-maps, xmlhttprequest, google-roads-api

I need to snap a Polyline to a road, and I found an [example from google that works really well](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap/). I tweak it a little bit, and then I get a NetworkError from JavaScript, saying that the response headers don't have an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. If I inspect the `responseText` from my XHR, it gives me [the standard Google 404 page](https://www.google.com.br/404).

Question is, how am I supposed to use the Roads API if it doesn't allow for cross-origin requests?

Code:

```
getSnappedPoints: function (path) { //path is an array of latlng
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var snappedCoords = new Array();
    var pathValues = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++)
        pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue());

    console.log(pathValues.join("|"));
    xhr.open("GET", "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?interpolate=true&path=" + pathValues.join("|") + "&key=MY_API_KEY", false);
    xhr.send();
    for (var i = 0; i < JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).snappedPoints.length; i++)
        snappedCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).snappedPoints[i].location.latitude, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).snappedPoints[i].location.longitude));
    return snappedCoords;
}
```

("MY_API_KEY" is just there because I don't want anyone using my quotas, I have replaced it with my browser key.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo) which is `https:`, if I try to access the web service from jsfiddle on `https` using `http:` or `http:` using `https`, I get the error you report.  It only works if you access the API via `https:` if your page is secure (running over `https:`), if your page is running over `http:` use `http:` to access the API.